# Scanner java not getting input in for loop

Tags: java, for-loop, java.util.scanner

i'm trying to get multiple input from Scanner in Java, the input need to be in a for loop.
Single input is working, as i put it in a for, the first cicle work as expected but the second stops at the first input.
Before the loop i get an integer, so i've put a scan.nextLine() to get the '\n' character, in the loop i work only with strings.

I tought the problem could be the stream close, but i need it to be open, closing it i get a scanner Exception.

```
public void scegliEsame(Medico m)
{
    Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
    String nome, data;

    System.out.print("Inserire numero di esami da prenotare: ");
    int ex=scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println();
    scan.nextLine();
    for(int i=0;i<ex;i++)
    {
        System.out.print("Inserire nome esame da voler effettuare: ");
        nome=scan.nextLine();

        if(m.getCosto(nome)==-1)
        {
            System.out.println("Esame non trovato");
            return;
        }
        else
            costo+=m.getCosto(nome);


        System.out.print("Inserire data di prenotazione: ");
        data=scan.nextLine();
        Esame e=new Esame(nome, m, data,costo);
        esami.add(e);
    }
}
```

Code method from class two

```
public void caricaEsami(Medico m)
{
    String esame;
    float costo;
    System.out.print("Inserire numero di esami totali: ");
    Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
    int n=scan.nextInt();
    scan.nextLine();
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        scan=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Inserire esame "+(i+1)+": ");
        esame=scan.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Inserire costo esame: ");
        costo=scan.nextFloat();
        Esame e=new Esame(esame, m, costo);
        m.setEsame(e);
        scan.nextLine();
    }
    medici.add(m);
}
```

I'm sorry for the italian language in my code, hope you could help me.

Comment: What do you mean by "*stops*"?

Comment: I tested your loop with `print` statements and it is working fine.  Your problem is likely somewhere in the code we can't see, try removing the calls to other classes and just print `data` and `nome` and you'll see those values are storing corretly.

Comment: The code worked fine for me to, maybe this condition is the issue `if(m.getCosto(nome)==-1)`

Comment: I've tested your code and the scanner is working fine. If I got your problem right, the "bug" is caused by the return statement inside your loop, which breaks the cycle.

Comment: I think the conclusion here is that this is something you need to figure out yourself, either by using a debugger or by adding print statements of variables in your code.

Comment: Thank you all for the answers, i've edited the question adding the code from class two, it's the other class where i use the Scanner
I think the problem is in there, maybe because i don't close the stream, but if i do, the execution give me a Scanner exception

Answer (score 0):

Since your question is a problem with Scanner, Can you check if this works alright for you ?  Most likely you have some other problem.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
        scegliEsame();
    }

    public static void scegliEsame(){
        Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
        String nome, data;

        System.out.print("Enter number of exams to be booked: ");
        int ex=scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println();
        scan.nextLine();
        for(int i=0;i<ex;i++)
        {
            System.out.print("Enter exam name you want to make: ");
            nome=scan.nextLine();
            System.out.println("You Entered: " + nome);

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code looks fine and it is working for me.

---

```
public class Test {

    List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test().scegliEsame();   
    }

    public void scegliEsame()
    {
        Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
        String nome, data;

        System.out.print("Inserire numero di esami da prenotare: ");
        int ex=scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println();
        scan.nextLine();

        for(int i=0;i<ex;i++)
        {
            System.out.print("Inserire nome esame da voler effettuare: ");
            nome=scan.nextLine();

            if(false)
            {
                System.out.println("Esame non trovato");
                return;
            }
            else
                list1.add(nome);


            System.out.print("Inserire data di prenotazione: ");
            data=scan.nextLine();
            list2.add(data);
        }
        System.out.println(list1+"\n\n"+list2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `nextLine()` more than one time you probably get this problem because it will take the `\n` from your first input as its input. To avoid that, use `next()`.

Comment: It's the other way round :). Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-or-nextfoo